# Dependency is not satisfiable: lib32gcc1 in Google Chrome

Tags: dependencies

I've tried to install Google Chrome for 32-bit .deb package. But it gave me the following errors:

```
 depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installable
                        depends: lib32stdc++6 (>= 4.6) but it is not installable
                        depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not installable
                        depends: libxss1 but it is not installable
```

Currently, I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 (32-bit - i386). So, when i try to install the dependency, it says me that i can't install.

I'm totally lost,I don't know what should I do.